# Nodejs TCP socket, when ending, does not contain remoteAddress information

Tags: sockets, node.js, tcp

I am building a simple echo server for the purposes of learning the fundamentals about building tcp services with node.js and figuring out what information is available.

When I am creating a server, as shown below, I can access information about the incomingSocket such as the remote address. Why is it that I cannot access the information on the closing of socket? Below is my code; my comment indicates the output I have received.

```
var net = require ( 'net' );
var server = net.createServer (
    function ( incomingSocket )
    {
        //'connection' listener
        console.log ( 'Connection from ' + incomingSocket.remoteAddress + ':' + incomingSocket.remotePort + " established." );

        incomingSocket.on (
            'data' ,
            function ( data )
            {
                // The incomingSocket.remoteAddress is defined here
                console.log ( incomingSocket.remoteAddress + ':' + incomingSocket.remotePort + ' -> ' + data.toString () );
            }
        );

        incomingSocket.on (
            'close' ,
            function ()
            {
                // The incomingSocket.remoteAddress is undefined here
                console.log ( 'connection from ' + incomingSocket.remoteAddress + ' closed.' );
            }
        );
        incomingSocket.pipe ( incomingSocket );
    }
);
// listening to a port happens here
```

I would appreciate any response! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well no, because when it gets in the event handler for the socket close event, the socket object no longer exists. If you need to display the remote address of the client as the socket is closing, simply store the remote address as the client initially connects.

```
var clients = new Array();

net.createServer(function(socket) {
   var remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress;
   var remotePort = socket.remotePort;

   // Add to array of clients
   clients.push(remoteAddress + ':' + remotePort);

   console.log('Connection from ' + remoteAddress  + ':' + remotePort + " established.");

   socket.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(remoteAddress + ':' + remotePort + ' -> ' + data.toString());
   });

   socket.on('close', function() {
      // Remove from array of clients
      clients.splice(clients.indexOf(remoteAddress + ':' + remotePort), 1);

      console.log('Connection from ' + remoteAddress + ':' + remotePort + ' closed.');
   });

   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for a response; I wanted to learn how to use the tcp server on node.js and I so I started on my goal of making a simple chatroom server out of it. I store a add to a list of connections that currently exist every time a new connection is made, and when data from one connection comes through, I send it through all the other connections. What I need to do is remove connections that disconnect, and in order to do this, I need to know their port and address so that  I can remove it from the list of connections.

How would I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Depends on how you store the remote address and port. What I would do is add the combination of them to an array when they connect, and remove them from the array when the socket is closed. The array must be defined in a scope where it is accessible in that `function(socket) {` closure.

Comment: That is what I did. When it came time to remove the socket from the array when it closes, the variable socket doesn't store anything.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you what I mean. You save the remote address and port into variables and you can use them even when the socket is closed.

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you so much! I realize now! You store it locally! Thank you for this :D